# athena generate table ddl output not working

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

In the AWS console (for Athena), one has the option of directly running the statement `` SHOW CREATE TABLE `foo`; `` or doing the same thing but via the GUI (in the tables option) to provide a single DDL (for that table).

I've created multiple DDLs this way and am now (just for experimentation) trying to run them for another database (`db2`, `db3`, ...). Here's one of them for example:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE db1.anomaly_eh_pred(
  "node" string, 
  "workzone_desc" string, 
  "eh_pred" double, 
  "create_dt" timestamp)
COMMENT "test"
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  "site_id" string, 
  "dt" date)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'escape.delim'='\\') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://foo/s3-stuff'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1616731896')
```

After trying to run this, I get the following error:

> line 1:8: mismatched input 'EXTERNAL'. Expecting: 'OR', 'SCHEMA', 'TABLE', 'VIEW'

This error is documented in other places ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67499445/amazon-athena-create-external-table-mismatched-input-external-invalidrequestex), [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/qaflz7/error_when_creating_table_from_parquet_file_in_s3/), and [here](https://repost.aws/questions/QU6YNvkkKRSTeyIbjb64klbA/athena-query-editor-behaving-unexpectedly)), and I've compared/tried those potential solution to no avail. Regardless, even if they did work, I'm confused why a raw, AWS-supplied DDL for an Athena table would simple not work. I've applied no editing whatsoever.

What could be a solution to this issue?

Comment: update to this: the DDL provided here (acquired via the AWS console) wasn't the same (or even executable) compared to what was run and versioned by the developers that managed this DDL.